# Retrieving days without outgoing Emails from MS Outlook via Python Win32com

Tags: python, python-3.x, outlook, win32com, office-automation

I need to find out in which days we haven't sent any email.
I used this code with `WinPython` and MS Office 2019 (`outlook`):

```
import win32com.client
import datetime

# Create an instance of Outlook
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")

# Access the inbox folder
inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(5).Items

# Set to store sent dates
sent_dates = set()
start_date = datetime.date(2022, 1, 1)
end_date = datetime.date(2023, 1, 1)

i = 0
for email in inbox:
    if email.Class == 43 and email.SentOn.date() >= start_date and email.SentOn.date() <= end_date:
        sent_dates.add(email.SentOn.date())
    print("Email", i)
    i += 1

# Create a range of dates within the specified date range
date_range = set(
    datetime.date.fromordinal(day) for day in range(
        start_date.toordinal(), end_date.toordinal() + 1
    )
)

# Exclude weekends (Saturday and Sunday)
date_range = {
    date for date in date_range if date.weekday() not in [5, 6]
}

# Find the workdays when you didn't send emails
workdays_without_emails = date_range - sent_dates

# Print workdays without sent emails
print("Workdays without sent emails:")
for day in sorted(workdays_without_emails):
    print(day)
```

It works when I had one year in the client and the rest in the exchange server. Then when I downloaded 2 years of emails, I ran again but now with this error when it reaches around 6600 emails:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xxxx\Downloads\WPy64-31150\scripts\outlook2.py", line 13, in <module>
    if correo.Class == 43 and correo.SentOn.date() >= start_date and correo.SentOn.date() <= end_date:
  File "C:\Users\xxxx\Downloads\WPy64-31150\python-3.11.5.amd64\Lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 627, in __getattr__
    ret = self._oleobj_.Invoke(retEntry.dispid, 0, invoke_type, 1)
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'An exception occurred.', (4096, 'Microsoft Outlook', 'The underlying security system cannot find the name of the digital identifier.', None, 0, -2146893792), None)
```

The permission issue did not appear when I tried with one year of emails.

```
Email 6624
Email 6625
Email 6626
Email 6627
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/xxx/Downloads/WPy64-31150/scripts/outlook3.py", line 17, in <module>
    if email.Class == 43 and email.SentOn.date() >= start_date and email.SentOn.date() <= end_date:
  File "C:\Users\xxx/Downloads\WPy64-31150\python-3.11.5.amd64\Lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 627, in __getattr__
    ret = self._oleobj_.Invoke(retEntry.dispid, 0, invoke_type, 1)
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'An exception occurred.', (4096, 'Microsoft Outlook', 'The underlying security system cannot find the name of the digital identifier.', None, 0, -2146893792), None)
```

any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Iterating over all items in the `Inbox` folder is not really a good idea:

```
for email in inbox:
    if email.Class == 43 and email.SentOn.date() >= start_date and email.SentOn.date() <= end_date:
        sent_dates.add(email.SentOn.date())
```

Instead, you can run a filter per day/week/month to find days/weeks/months that don't have emails sent out. Read more about the `Find`/`FindNext` or `Restrict` methods of the `Items` class in the articles that I wrote for the technical blog more than a decade ago:

- [How To: Use Find and FindNext methods to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder (C#, VB.NET)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/outlook-find-findnext-retrieve-mail/)
- [How To: Use Restrict method to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/outlook-restrict-method-retrieve-mail/)